# Show records for specific user - Laravel-admin panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

I'm using laravel-admin panel and I'm trying to figure out how I can display only the records from "order" table that has the name of the Developer that is logged in. I read the documentation but I didn't find any solution for this specific case. Would be really glad if anyone could help me.

Here's My OrdersController.php:

```
  protected function grid()
    { 
            if (Admin::user()->isRole('Developer')) {
                $grid = DB::table('order')
                ->where('developer', Admin::user()->username)
                ->get();
            }
     
      
        $grid = new Grid(new Order());

        $grid->column('id', __('Id'));
        $grid->column('customer_name', __('Customer name'));
        $grid->column('email', __('Email'));
        $grid->column('mobile', __('Mobile'));
        $grid->column('project_name', __('Project name'));
        $grid->column('categoria', __('Categoria'));
        $grid->column('contact', __('Contact'));
        $grid->column('domain', __('Domain'));
        $grid->column('new_domain', __('New domain'));
        $grid->column('alojamento', __('Alojamento'));
        $grid->column('criar_email', __('Criar email'));
        $grid->column('facebook', __('Facebook'));
        $grid->column('instagram', __('Instagram'));
        $grid->column('linkedin', __('Linkedin'));
        $grid->column('plan', __('Plan'));
        $grid->column('payment', __('Payment'));
        $grid->column('payment_date', __('Payment date'));
        $grid->column('order_date', __('Order date'));
        $grid->column('state', __('State'));
        $grid->column('developer', __('Developer'));

        return $grid;
    }
```

Comment: Your definition of `$grid = DB::table(...)` is completely pointless the way your code is defined currently; you override it below with `$grid = new Grid(....)`. If you did `return $grid = DB::table(...)` then it will work. Remember that code execution will continue to happen from top to bottom until you explicitly exit (via `return` in this case)

Comment: @TimLewis I've tried to "return $grid = DB::table(...)" as you mentioned, but it only returns me the array values, not in a grid

Comment: Well of course, you're never calling `new Grid()` before you return `$grid`. I'm not sure what a `Grid` is or how it works, but you should be able to debug your own code and determine why something isn't happening. If `Grid` is compatible with multiple orders, then you can do `return new Grid(DB::table(...)->get());`, otherwise you'll need to do `return new Grid(DB::table(...))->first());`